# Form Redirect Success/Fail page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, redirect

I have tried to make my form redirect to a success or fail page. I have searched all through the internet, looking at normal form redirects and even javascript onClick redirect's. Can someone help me add with adding a redirect:

HTML:

```
<!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
   <!-- CONTACT FORM -->
   <div class="col-lg-6">
   <h1>CONTACT</h1>

         <h3 class="service_h3">Say Hello! Ask something?</h3>               

           <form action="submit_contact.php" id="contactForm">

            <fieldset>
            <div id="result"></div>

               <!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
               <!-- NAME FIELD -->
                <div class="form-item">
                <label for="name">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" required/>
                </label>
                </div>

               <!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
               <!-- EMAIL FIELD -->
                <div class="form-item">
                <label for="email">
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" required/>
                </label>
                </div>

               <!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
               <!-- MESSAGE FIELD -->
                <div class="form-item">
                <label for="message">
                <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your Message" required></textarea>
                </label>
                </div>

               <!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
               <!-- SUBMIT BUTTON -->
                <div class="form-item">
                <button name="submit" class="submit_btn" action="submit_contact.php" window.open("Done") type="submit">Submit</button>


                </div>

            </fieldset>

           </form>

         </div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

/* Subject and Email Variables*/

$emailSubject = 'Contact Form Submission';
$webMaster = 'no-reply@*Hidden*.com';

/* Gathering Data Variables */

$nameField = $_POST['name'];
$emailField = $_POST['email'];
$messageField = $_POST['message'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$hostaddress = gethostbyaddr($ip);
$browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$referred = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

$body = <<<EOD
<br><img src="*Hidden*"> <br>GoAerox! Network - Contact Form Submission<hr><br>
<strong>Name:</strong> $nameField <br>
<strong>Email:</strong>  $emailField <br>
<strong>Message:</strong>  $messageField <br><br>
<hr><br><strong>User Details</strong><br>
<strong>IP Address:</strong>  $ip <br>
<strong>Host address:</strong>  $hostaddress <br>
<strong>Browser:</strong>  $browser <br>
<strong>Referred:</strong>  $referred <br>
EOD;

$headers = "From: $emailField\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);

/* Results rendered as HTML */

$theResults = <<<EOD
<html>
**RESULT PAGE**
</html>
EOD;

echo "$theResults";




?>
```

Please give an answer that is easily read by a amatuer PHP coder. Note: I am happy for this to redirect to a page or popup on the actual contact page. As long as the user can see that the form has been submitted without error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to redirect to your success or fail page

```
    <?php
            $emailSubject = 'Contact Form Submission';
            $webMaster = 'no-reply@*Hidden*.com';

            $nameField = $_POST['name'];
            $emailField = $_POST['email'];
            $messageField = $_POST['message'];
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $hostaddress = gethostbyaddr($ip);
            $browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
            $referred = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
            $body = <<<EOD
            <br><img src="*Hidden*"> <br>GoAerox! Network - Contact Form Submission<hr><br>
            <strong>Name:</strong> $nameField <br>
            <strong>Email:</strong>  $emailField <br>
            <strong>Message:</strong>  $messageField <br><br>
            <hr><br><strong>User Details</strong><br>
            <strong>IP Address:</strong>  $ip <br>
            <strong>Host address:</strong>  $hostaddress <br>
            <strong>Browser:</strong>  $browser <br>
            <strong>Referred:</strong>  $referred <br>
            EOD;

            $headers = "From: $emailField\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
            $success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);
            header('location:success.php');
    ?>
```

Comment: Where would I place this?

Comment: You can place this code instead of the following code

$theResults = <<<EOD
<html>
**RESULT PAGE**
</html>
EOD;

Comment: What happen when you run this code ? Did you get any error messages ?

Comment: No, well when I run the html scrip, it sends the email but doesn't redirect.

Comment: I just tried to run the php by itself and it said:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'header' (T_STRING) in /submit_contact.php on line 37

Comment: Paste my code on the top of the page, then run, In this way we can check the code is working or not ...

Comment: It redirects to the success page; however the code does not send the email.

Comment: Ok, Place my code in the previous position , place the following code on the top of the page, then try

ob_start();

Also avoid white space before starting position of the page

Comment: Does the exact same thing... Not sure why.

Comment: I have updated my code, It working good for me. Please use my entire code once again. Still it is not working something wrong in your system. We need to do a detailed diagnosis in your code

Comment: Did you fix the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

$redirecturl ="Your thank you page url"
header('Location: '.$redirecturl);

Use header function to redirect to another page.

Place this function after your mail function completed.

Comment: Where would I place this?

Comment: look in the link i gave *before* any output